# Interpreting a qq plot

Tags: biostatistics, qq-plot

Simple question, I'm new to biostatistics and the interpretation of qq-plots. What does this qq-plot say about the distribution of my sample? Is it bimodal?

[image]

Comment: Comparing it to `qqnorm(c(rbeta(44000, 50, 50), rbeta(21000,1,1)*0.6 + 0.2))` might give you some insight.

Comment: Magic! Where do you keep the secret recipe?

Comment: did you find out in the end what this meant?